# Why do Americans pronounce "Noo York" the way they do?

Tags: pronunciation, history, historical-change, yod-dropping

I'm wondering if there is a historical explanation as to why the `New` in "New York" is pronounced /nu/ (as in "Noodles") rather than /nju/ (as in RP "New Year").

Has this always been the case? Or did the pronunciation change over time?

Comment: In my American English, "new" is noo in both "New York" and "new year".  In British English, "ew" is a falling diphthong beginning with y (yod).  The y may well be kept in some American English.

Comment: I personally pronounce *new* and *noo* identically.

Comment: I'm not American, but judging by American TV and movies Americans commonly pronounce *new* as *noo* in all contexts. Conversely I pronounce it *nyoo* in all contexts including when saying *New York*.

Comment: An interesting pair of words is "Cuba" and "tuba".  They shouldn't rhyme, but in the US most people accomplish this by mispronouncing *both* of them, adding a glide to "Cuba" and dropping it from "tuba".

Comment: This brings up the question as to when and where the yod was -introduced-, given that none of these terms had it in Old English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [yod-dropping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping):

> Yod -dropping .....  was formerly considered nonstandard in England, but is today also heard among well-educated [RP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) speakers. (The /j/ after /s/ is not normally dropped in RP in medial positions, however – compare pursuit /pəˈsjuːt/.) *In General American yod-dropping is found.......... also in:*
>
> After /t/, /d/ and /n/, for example tune /ˈtuːn/, dew /ˈduː/, ***new /ˈnuː/***

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 3):

The phonetician J. C. Wells in his *Accents of English* (1982) gives an historical account of the phenomenon known as yod-dropping, which can be seen in the pronunciation of *new* as /nu/ as opposed to /nju/.  I'll try to sum up his views by providing some excerpts from his book:

> Pairs such as *threw*-*through*, *brewed*-*brood* used to be distinguished by the use of a diphthong in the former member of each pair as against a monophthong in the latter.  The diphthong of the /ɪŭ/ type, developed into a rising /ju/ through the transfer of syllabicity from the first segment to the second; in certain environments the /j/ then disappeared, a development we may refer to as early yod dropping.  The pairs mentioned are accordingly homophones in most accents.
>
> In London the falling diphthong /ɪŭ/ had by the end of the 17th century given way to a rising /ĭu/, phonetically identical with the inherited /ju/ of *youth* etc.  This development brought into existence a large number of new initial consonant clusters involving /j/.  Several of them were intrinsically awkward to pronounce, so that we find that from the beginning of the 18th century the /ĭ/or /j/ element disappeared in certain environments, leaving a vowel identical with /u/ and creating new homophones such as *threw*-*through*.
>
> The environments in which early yod dropping applied most generally are (i) after palatals (including palato-alevolars), as in *chute*, *chew*, *juice*, *yew*; (ii) after /r/, as in *rude*, *crew*, *shrew*, *grew*; and (iii) after consonant plus /l/, as in *blue*, *flue*, *blew*, *glue*.
>
> The accents of East Anglia are notable for having extended yod dropping to most or all postconsonantal environments, for example in *few* /fu/, *music* /muzɪk/, cube /kub/, *Hugh* /hu/.
>
> Other accents occupy intermediate positions, retaining /j/ after labial, velars and /h/, but perhaps not after some alveolars.
>
> In RP there is variability in the environment of a preceding /θ, s, z, l/ as in *enthusiasm* /ɪn'θ(j)uzɪæzm/, *suit* /s(j)ut/, *lewd* /l(j)ud/; the yod is consistently retained after /n/, as in /nju/ *new*, and also after /t, d/, as in *tune* /tjun/, *duke* /djuk/ (where there is the further possibility in casual speech of yod coalescence to /tʃun/, /dʒuk/).
>
> In General American, and also in part of the south and midlands of England, /j/ is lost after alveolars /t, d, n, l, s, z/ but not after labials or velars.  In these environments General American predominantly has plain /u/, thus *tune* /tun/, *duke* /duk/, *new* /nu/ etc.  Some easterners and southerners, however, have either /ju/ or the diphthong /ɪu/, and General American is not entirely uniform.